# Circular transparency with MagickImage C#

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I want to make a 256x256 image transparent based on the distance to the center. In the center, the transparency is 0%, at a distance of 128 or more pixels, the transparency should be 100%. 
Original image

[image: original image]

It should look just about like this
[image]

I tried like this

```
MagickImage image2 = new MagickImage("2.jpg");

image2.Format = MagickFormat.Png;
image2.Alpha(AlphaOption.Set);
MagickImage copy = new MagickImage(image2.Clone());
copy.BackgroundColor = MagickColors.None;
copy.Vignette(64, 64, 64, 64);
image2.Composite(copy, CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);
copy.Write("3.jpg");
```

result(cross in the center)
[image]

I tried like this

```
MagickImage image = new MagickImage("2.jpg");
image.Alpha(AlphaOption.Set);
image.VirtualPixelMethod = VirtualPixelMethod.Transparent;
image.Blur(0, 128, Channels.Alpha);
image.Level(new Percentage(50), new Percentage(100), Channels.Alpha);
image.Write("soft_edge.png");
```

result(cross in the center)
[image]

Can you suggest an easy way to implement this?

Comment: Why are you not trying a radial gradient? (Examples of how to do it with ImageMagick's commandline: https://imagemagick.org/script/gradient.php)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thanks, but the command line is not suitable for me, I need to work directly with the library from C # WinForm

Comment: I know, but i hoped you could take the command line examples as guidance or inspiration of how to possibly achieve similar results through Magick.NET's API (after all, one can expect that the ImageMagick features accessible through the CLI should also be accessible in some way through Magick.NET's API).